# no matching operator delete found; memory will not be freed if initialization throws an exception

Tags: c++

I have made a BaseObject class that overrides the new (and delete) operators, so I can log memory as it is created and destroyed during the lifecycle of my application, making it easy for me to spot any unreleased memory.

However, I am getting the following errors when I compile (but it runs fine):

**resourcemanager.h(36): warning C4291: 'void *BaseObject::operator new(size_t,const char *,int)': no matching operator delete found; memory will not be freed if initialization throws an exception**

**baseobject.h(8): note: see declaration of 'BaseObject::operator new'**

My BaseObject class looks like this:

```
class BaseObject
{
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size, const char* file, int line);
    void* operator new[](size_t size, const char* file, int line);

    void operator delete(void* ptr);
    void operator delete[](void* ptr);
};

#define MY_NEW new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define MY_DELETE delete(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

From what I read on the internet, the problem is due to the fact that the overridden delete operators need matching signatures. So in this case, it should work if I added "const *char file, int line" to the delete operators. But then I run into another problem as I cannot call delete on any objects since it is not finding a matching delete operator (it must now take file and line as input). Using the MY_DELETE macro above does not work in this case as delete cannot use parameters like that.

Pretty much at a loss here.

EDIT:

The solution was not immediately obvious. Adding overridden delete functions with the same extra parameters as the new functions was not enough since this yielded a problem with there being "no non-placement delete operator". This in turn could be solved by adding a non-placement delete operator. So, the class looks like this now (and it is working):

```
class BaseObject
{
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size, const char* file, int line);
    void* operator new[](size_t size, const char* file, int line);

    // Placement delete functions, matching overridden new functions
    void operator delete(void* ptr, const char* file, int line);
    void operator delete[](void* ptr, const char* file, int line);

    // Non-placement delete functions
    void operator delete(void* ptr);
    void operator delete[](void* ptr);
};
```

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on gcc or clang

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: May i ask why you don't just put your logging in Contructor + Destructor instead of trying to overload new/delete? You shouldn't manually call delete if youre writing modern c++ anyways.

Comment: `class BaseObject abstract` what's that `abstract` there for? It won't compile like this.

Comment: I also [cannot reproduce](https://rextester.com/BWLO34088) with `19.00.23506`, so I'm guessing visual studio bug?

Comment: @Eric: this way, I do not have to write the logging every time I create a new constructor. It would be tedious.

Comment: @AndyG: It says that the class is abstract and cannot be instantiated. It is a base class, which must be derived from. It cannot be created itself.

Comment: @Christoffer The problem is, for your logging to work it's nessecary to manually call delete to free your objects. You simply shouldn't do that anymore. You should take a look at memory management using C++ 11 smart pointers. This simplifies memory management by a lot, so you might not even need logging for it anymore. Also "class BaseObject abstract" is not valid C++. You can't declare a whole class abstract like in other languages, this simply isn't a thing. C++ Classes become not instantiable automatically by having at least one pure virtual function (example: virtual void foo() = 0; )

Comment: The abstract thing is a remnant from RT, please ignore that. I have used smart pointers in the past, but they are unwieldy as intellisense fails 10 out 10 on those, for me. I decided to get rid of them and log memory in debug instead. For me, that is better and allows me to sleep peacefully :)

Answer (score 3):

From cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new :

> If initialization terminates by throwing an exception (e.g. from the
>   constructor), if new-expression allocated any storage, it calls the
>   appropriate deallocation function: `operator delete` for non-array type,
>   `operator delete[]` for array type. The deallocation function is looked
>   up in global scope if the new-expression used the `::new` syntax,
>   otherwise it is looked up in the scope of `T`, if `T` is a class type. If
>   the failed allocation function was usual (non-placement), lookup for
>   the deallocation function follows the rules described in
>   delete-expression. **For a failed placement new, all parameter types,
>   except the first, of the matching deallocation function must be
>   identical to the parameters of the placement new. The call to the
>   deallocation function is made the value obtained earlier from the
>   allocation function passed as the first argument, alignment passed as
>   the optional `alignment` argument (since C++17), and `placement_params`,
>   if any, passed as the additional placement arguments. If no
>   deallocation function is found, memory is not deallocated.**

So the matching signature for delete in your case is:

1. strip away `size`
2. put `void* ptr` in its place
3. repeat the parameters passed to `operator new`.

This leads to:

```
class BaseObject
{
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size, const char* file, int line);
    void* operator new[](size_t size, const char* file, int line);

    void operator delete(void* ptr, const char* file, int line);
    void operator delete[](void* ptr, const char* file, int line);
};
```

Off-topic: abstract is not a keyword in C++ and this should be a compile error. To make a class abstract, define a function as pure virtual (by putting `= 0` as its definition).

Comment: Doing this yields the following error:

'SceneManager': cannot delete pointers to objects of this type; the class has no non-placement overload for 'operator delete'.

For each "delete x;" that I call.

Comment: @Christoffer well a SceneManger is not mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: No, whatever class I try to delete, it won't compile due to that error. Just took the first line, so the SceneManager is irrelevant. Beginning to understand that people here do not seem to understand the problem, so maybe I have stumbled onto something new in the world of C++ (that actually worked 10 years ago when I did this the last time).

Comment: @Christoffer We have no code to reproduce. Then you suddenly bring in a different class which is mentioned nowhere. What shall we do? Guess what you coded? Give us a minimal example that we can copy&paste and compile and get the error ourself.

Comment: Well, I solved it. Was a completely different problem, which was minimalistically explained on the C++ sites I frequent. Strange… Simply added another pair of delete functions, without any additional params.

Comment: @Christoffer Then share your solutions with us so the next person encountering the problems can find a solution too.